# Why does update_idletasks() interfere with overrideredirect() functionality?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a top-level window, whose specific location is set via geometry string. `w.overrideredirect(True)` is called because the top-level window mustn't have any window manager decorations. The [official documentation](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/tkinter.pdf) states:

> Be sure to call the .update_idletasks() method (see Section 26,
> “Universal widget methods”(p. 97)) before setting this flag.

So that's exactly what I did, but now window manager decorations appear. It works fine if I don't call `w.update_idletasks()`.

Code:

```
w = tk.Toplevel(self.parent_frame)
w.geometry('48x240+1567+209')
w.update_idletasks()
w.overrideredirect(True)
```

I'm using Python 3.8.10 with Tk version 8.6.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not official documentation, and it is wrong. The exact opposite is true: you must set the flag *before* tkinter has the chance to draw the window on the screen. That means before `mainloop` is started, and before any calls to `update` or `update_idletasks`.

The reasoning is simple: setting the `overrideredirect` merely sets a flag. When the window is rendered, tkinter will look to see if the flag is set and then draw the window. If the flag is not set, a border is added to the window.

Setting the flag after the window has already been drawn will have no effect since the border will already have been drawn.